# C# Equivalent of Java's GenericType<?>

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working with some generics in C#. I have an abstract generic class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : Foo { }
```

and the type parameter is specified when other classes inherit from the base class.

I'm also trying to write some code for another abstract class that needs to store one of these base classes, but it won't know the parameter of the base class (and it doesn't need to know). In Java I could simple write:

```
protected BaseClass<?> myBaseClass;
```

But in C# it insists I give it a type parameter. If I declare it as:

```
protected BaseClass<Foo> myBaseClass;
```

I cannot assign any parametrized values of `BaseClass` to it.

Is there a work around to achieve the effect of `BaseClass<?>` in C#? Obviously there are ways to restructure my code to avoid the need, such as parameterizing all of the classes that use `BaseClass` as well, but this would be less than ideal. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: define doesn't need to know.  In the c# world it does need to know.

Comment: By using the <?> syntax, you are taking advantage of the fact that a generic type in Java isn't actually it's own type, but just syntactic sugar. C# has better (more strict, reifiable) generic types, and a side effect of that is that you need to give the type parameter in all declarations.

Comment: This question seems to be attracting a lot of downvoting in the answers for some reason. Outside of the work arounds suggested by the poster there is no way to achieve for BaseClass<?> functionality of Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match Java's behavior somewhat in C#, it is common to put an additional *non-generic* interface in the inheritance hierarchy.

```
public interface IBaseClass
{
    Foo GetValue();

    void SetValue(Foo value);
}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBaseClass
    where T : Foo
{
    public T GetValue<T>()
    { /* ... */ }

    public void SetValue<T>(T value)
    { /* ... */ }

    Foo IBaseClass.GetValue()    // Explicit interface method implementation
    {
        return (Foo)GetValue<T>();
    }

    void IBaseClass.SetValue(Foo value)    // Explicit interface method impl.
    {
        SetValue<T>((T)value);
    }
}
```

And then use `IBaseClass` where you need `BaseClass<?>`:

```
IBaseClass myClass;
Foo f = myClass.GetValue();
```

Comment: I don't remember off hand - Is the cast in the IBaseClass.GetValue() implementation really required?

Comment: @SimonLindgren In most cases it is probably not required. But if `Foo` is `object` and `T` is a value type, then it _is_ required.

Comment: This seems like a bit of overkill for what I'm doing, but it seems like the most well structured solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look like there are two accounts actively downvoting most of the answers here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't know what accounts they are. I only noticed that all the answers here (including the five deleted ones) have either no votes, or _two or more downvotes_.

Comment: @Virtlink: Doh! *(looks chagrined)* Sorry, wasn't on my game yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The classes using this type will also need to be generic, if you don't yet know the generic argument of that class yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the wildcard in a parameter declaration to a method, then you'll need to make the method generic:

```
void printBaseClass<T>(BaseClass<T> o) where T : Foo {
  // ...
}
```

If you're using this as a variable type declaration, just use `var`.

```
var o = GetBaseClassOfSomeType();
```

Comment: what does `var` have to do with generics?

Comment: @HighCore: Not writing the generic type in the variable declaration. But maybe I just missed some part of the question the OP asked.